# Añadir icono al inicio de un TextView en Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Para insertar un icono como prefijo en una cadena de texto recurro a símbolos [unicode utf8](http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/), pero me pregunto si hay otra manera.

Se puede asignar un icono, `Drawable` cómo prefijo en un `TextView`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Se puede hacer mediante programación con la función `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds` del `TextView`, Ejemplo:

```
//izquierda
txtview.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.image, 0, 0, 0);
//parte superior
txtview.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.image, 0, 0);
//derecha
txtview.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.image, 0);
//parte inferior
txtview.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, R.drawable.image);
```

O a través del Xml con los parámetros `android:drawableLeft`, `android:drawableRight`, `android:drawableBottom` y `android:drawableTop`. Ejemplo:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtStatus"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/image"
    android:drawablePadding="5dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="@string/name"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Tienes 2 maneras, una como comentan, dependiendo en donde quieres colocar la imagen

```
//izquierda
tuTextView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.gatito, 0, 0, 0);
//parte superior
tuTextView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.gatito, 0, 0);
//derecha
tuTextView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.gatito, 0);
//Al fondo
tuTextView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, R.drawable.gatito);
```

La otra forma es usando `SpannableString`:

```
SpannableString tuTexto= new SpannableString("Mira mi gatito");
tuTexto.setSpan(new ImageSpan(getActivity(), R.drawable.gatito), 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
tuTextView.setText(tuTexto);
```